# how to generalise elastic search code for more than 3 skills

Tags: python, elasticsearch

Presently my elastic search query can work up to 3 skills. How can I generalize this below-mentioned query for any number of skills

For quicker sollution, I duplicated the code for each skill.

```
def results(indexedfiles, query_skills_list):

    if len(query_skills_list) == 3:
        search_results = indexedfiles.search(
            index="indexed_rem",
            doc_type="rem1",
            body={
                "_source": ["Filename", "SkillsFound"],
                "from": 0,
                "size": 10,
                "query": {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [
                            {"match_phrase": {"SkillsFound": query_skills_list[0]}},
                            {"match_phrase": {"SkillsFound": query_skills_list[1]}},
                            {"match_phrase": {"SkillsFound": query_skills_list[2]}},
                        ]
                    }
                },
            },
        )

    return search_results
```

How can I generalize this code for any number of skills?

Answer (score 0):

Create your must clause list where your skills counter is SKILLS_COUNT.

```
must_query = [{'match_phrase': {'SkillsFound': query_skills_list[i]}} for i in range(SKILLS_COUNT)]
```

and set it in your code with `'must': must_query`.